# Invalid AWS role or insufficient permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-swarm

I followed the [Link Amazon Web Services to Docker Cloud](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/cloud-swarm/link-aws-swarm/) article step-by-step and successfully generated a role ARN, but when I enter the ARN to link my docker cloud account, I'm getting the following error message

> Invalid AWS role or insufficient permissions

I'm not sure if the error is caused by one of these prerequisites

> Note: Your AWS account must support EC2-VPC to deploy swarms, and you
>   must also have an SSH key in each AWS region you deploy swarms in.

How do I check if my AWS account support EC2-VCP and how do I know which AWS region I'm deploying swarms in?

Answer (score 0):

Since Docker Cloud is shutting down in less than 60 days, I wouldn't recommend building any new swarms with it :) https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/migration/